# While reader loop C# with Unknown Columns

Tags: c#, mysql, datareader

Trying to loop through a MySQL data reader object using

```
while (rdr.ToString())
{
OSTicketDataList.Add(rdr[0].ToString());   
OSTicketDataList.Add(rdr[1].ToString());                      
OSTicketDataList.Add(rdr[2].ToString());                    
OSTicketDataList.Add(rdr[3].ToString()); 
OSTicketDataList.Add(rdr[4].ToString());
```

}

The reader query is in a method, so the query itself can be different.  If the reader contains less than 4 columns, than I get an index was out of bounds error.

How can I infinitely loop the rdr so that I don't have to define each field?

I am having difficulty trying to conceptualize this so I apologize for the noob question if it's something simple I am missing.

Thank you!

Comment: Assuming the reader implements `IDataReader`, there is a `FieldCount` property. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idatareader(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: If you are using the standard [MySqlDataReader Class](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-net/6.10/html/T_MySql_Data_MySqlClient_MySqlDataReader.htm) it also has a [FieldCount](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-net/6.10/html/P_MySql_Data_MySqlClient_MySqlDataReader_FieldCount.htm) property

Comment: Unsure how noob we're talking here, but it's entirely possible that saying "there's a FieldCount" property is insufficient to help OP. Inside the while loop (which has a weird condition -- presumably that should use rdr.Read()), you need a for loop that looks something like for(int i = 0; i < rdr.FieldCount - 1; i++) and within that loop you should add rdr[i].ToString() to your list.

Comment: I was playing around with .FieldCount but couldn't figure out how to incorporate that.  but you solved my issue... so the reader field number can be a variable!

Thank you so much Trioj.